# How to convert AM PM string into timestamp in latest version of spark(3.0)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have found few good solutions but they do not work with the latest version of spark.
Like this one!

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sc.parallelize([Row(visit_dts='5/1/2018 3:48:14 PM')]).toDF()

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

web = df.withColumn("web_datetime", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp("visit_dts",'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa'),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
```

```
Expecting: 

web.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+
|          visit_dts|       web_datetime|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|5/1/2018 3:48:14 PM|05/01/2018 15:48:14|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Actual output:

org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to recognize 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy' pattern in the DateTimeFormatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "M" instead of "MM" for numbers without padding i.e. without 0 prefixes and "a" instead of "aa" for Spark 3+, see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['5/1/2018 3:48:14 PM']]).toDF("visit_dts")
df.withColumn("visit_dts_new", F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp("visit_dts",'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a'),'M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss')).show()
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]